# Git: Архив с изменёнными файлами

Tags: git

В общем создавать архив вручную с изменёнными файлами сайта мне уже надоело. В инете пишут что для таких целей используют Git. Посмотрел видео, читал статьи. Научился создавать локальный репозитории, коммиты и пр. (основы в общем). Но я нигде не нашёл инфы о том (точнее нашёл, но я нечего толком не понял), как создать архив ТОЛЬКО с изменёнными файлами с сохранением путей до них (т.е с папками). Собственно в этом и вопрос. Или может есть способ легче? Например без использования Git?

Comment: .......А зачем?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: @Духсообщества К примеру изначально я создал комиит 1, затем внёс правки например в index.php и создал коммит 2. Теперь мне нужно извлечь в архив файлы, которые были изменены относительно коммита 1. Т.е все файлы которые изменились с момента Коммита 1. С сохранением путей к ним. Вместе с папками

Comment: @QS-12 а зачем?

Comment: Лучше скажите, не что вам нужно, а для чего.

Comment: Архив мне нужен чтобы залить его на хостинг. Сейчас я создаю его вручную, т.е все новые/изменённые файлы и папки я перетаскиваю в архив, а потом загружаю его на хостинг. Когда изменений становиться много, то вручную его собирать нудно и долго. Я прошу прощения если выражаюсь не совсем понятно. Проще говоря на выходе должен получится архив с новыми и/или изменёнными файлами. Лучше на примере:

Коммит 1: css, index.php; Коммит 2: css, lib, index.php (изменённый); Получить архив: lib, index.php

Comment: @QS-12 Нужно наладить работу через git. Льете изменения в гитлаб или гитхаб. Сервер их забирает по ручной команде или автоматически при настроенных pipelineах.

Comment: @QS-12 Почему просто не заливать весь проект на хостинг? По-моему это значительно проще

Comment: Делайте docker образ и деплойте его.

Answer (score 3):

Можно попробовать следующую команду:

```
git archive -o update.zip sha1 $(git diff --name-only sha1 sha2)
```

sha1, sha2 - это, хэши соседних коммитов соответственно

заархивируются файлы, измененные между двумя указанными  коммитами

---

или

```
git archive -o update.zip HEAD $(git diff --name-only HEAD HEAD^)
```

заархивируются файлы, измененных последним коммитом

---

Док по архивации данных гита: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-archive

Comment: Вот! Спасибо большое! То что нужно! Теперь обновления легче будет делать. Спасибо ещё раз

Comment: Хорошо, но недостаточно для реальной бизнес-задачи "внесения **всех** изменений" - забыта сущность "новые файлы", и я уж совсем молчу про удаленные

Comment: @LazyBadger новые файлы на сколько я знаю тоже вносятся, удалённые - логично, что нет. Но это уже усмотрение автора. По мне так проще весь проект копировать и не исхищряться

Answer (score 1):

Если под Windows то вместо git'а можно использовать команду robocopy

`robocopy` автоматически определяет, какие файлы были изменены и копирует только их

Например, вы даёте команду робокопи на ту папку, где лежит ваш сайт. Эта папка копируется в архив, но при этом копируются только те файлы, которые изменились. Если надо полностью скопировать сайт, то тогда используется команда `copy`

В отличие от git команда робокопи не сохраняет историю вашего сайта по типу википедии. В википедии вы можете увидеть абсолютно все изменения страницы, точно так же как и в гит. Если вам не нужна эту функциональность и вам не надо видеть историю изменений, то вам достаточно одной команды - robocopy и затем команда - свернуть папку в архив ( при необходимости хранить именно в сжатом виде )

Comment: Я на Linux, но всё равно спасибо

Comment: Возможно есть аналог этой команды для Linux

Comment: Я позже посмотрю об этой команде в интернете. Вполне возможно что в будущем она мне пригодится. А если и нет, то знать нужно хотя бы для общего развития

Answer (score 1):

> В инете пишут что для таких целей используют Git

Врут. Или, если мягче, "недоговаривают многие значимые детали" - о том, что используется определенный GUI, или о том, что это не про чистый Гит, а вообще Гитхаб с хуками, или что нужен только POSIX-shell, или репо с обеих сторон опять же с хуками

Суровая правда состоит в том, что одной вменяемой родной команды для этого нет, и надо, как обычно, лепить костыли из говна и палок. Самая близкая [итерация](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71250666/960558), что я нашел, делает только список файлов, осталось только на эту заготовку навертеть копирование в отдельное дерево

Но я бы посоветовал вместо этого сменить рабочий процесс веб-разработки из нулевых на что-то более вменяемое или сменить инструмент: в TortoiseHG | Mercurial мне для выполнения требуемой по задаче операции требуется 3 клика мышью или 1 консольная (родная для меруриала) команда